How can I automatically start a background service to send notifications after the phone reboots?
i am a new Java learner. I attempted to implement a background service to start after rebooting to send the notification.
Here is the code I tried.
/MainActivity.java/
package com.example.BgService;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {
    private MyBroadcastReceiver bootReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Register the broadcast receiver to handle BOOT_COMPLETED action
        bootReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter bootFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            bootFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED);
        }
        registerReceiver(bootReceiver, bootFilter);

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (bootReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(bootReceiver);
        }
    }
}

/MyBroadcastReceiver.java/
package com.example.BgService;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("RebootCompleted");
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()) || Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Boot Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
            } else {
                context.startService(serviceIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}

/MyService.java/
package com.example.BgService;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1337;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "MyServiceChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannel();

        // Build your notification
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My Awesome App")
                .setContentText("Doing some work...")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .build();

        // Set the notification as foreground
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // If the service is killed by the system, it will be restarted with the last intent
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "My Service Channel";
            String description = "Channel for My Service";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}

AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name=".MyService" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

I have tried this code, but I am unable to receive notifications automatically after the device (phone) restarts. Please help me solve this.
